# C# RDLC Page Break on Rectangle

Tags: c#, reporting-services, report, rdlc

I have problem with page break on RDLC report, Visual Studio 2005.

I have report like this:

[image: Report sample]

Text "Other items title" and Table below, is contained by rectangle:
[image: Contained by]

**PageBreakAtStart** is set to **True** on rectangle2.

It all works until I set Visible condition to rectangle2. When Visible condition is set, there is no page break. No matters is rectangle2 visible or not. 
Condition is true when table contained by rectangle2 has rows.
How to solove this?

Answer (score 1):

Ah... I found solution

I have following:
Rectangle, which contains table and text.

If i separate Visibility condition and PageBreak propery, it works. 
I think it's bug in VS2005.

Solution is:

Add one more rectangle.
Move old rectangle with content in new rectangle.
Set old rectangle page break property how do you want (to end or to start).
Set new rectangle visibility condition.

It now works :D

If someone has more clean solution, it will be cool :)